# Sparse arrays from tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I searched the net to find a guide for Scipy sparse matrices and I failed. I would be happy if anybody would share any source for it but now going to question:

I have an array of tuples. I want to change the array of tuples to a sparse matrix where the tuples appear on the main diagonal and diagonal just beside to it as the following example shows it. What is the fancy(efficient) way of doing it?

```
import numpy as np
A=np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
B=np.zeros((A.shape[0],A.shape[0]+1))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    B[i,i]=A[i,0]
    B[i,i+1]=A[i,1]
print B
```

Output being:

```
[[ 1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  5.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  7.  8.]]
```

Comment: Probably this is the silliest way I guess.

Comment: The primary source of information on the scipy sparse package is its reference page: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html.  However this not a refined user or beginners guide.  Keep in mind that this package is still under development.  Matlab's sparse matricies might have better documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build those really fast as a CSR matrix:

```
>>> A = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
>>> rows = len(A)
>>> cols = rows + 1
>>> data = A.flatten() # we want a copy
>>> indptr = np.arange(0, len(data)+1, 2) # 2 non-zero entries per row
>>> indices = np.repeat(np.arange(cols), [1] + [2] * (cols-2) + [1])
>>> import scipy.sparse as sps
>>> a_sps = sps.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(rows, cols))
>>> a_sps.A
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please give me also a source for this sparse matrices if you know any.

Comment: The [wikipedia page on sparse matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) is a great starting point on what those three arrays (`data`, `indices` and `indptr`) are. Getting to know them often enables doing things that are (at least currently) beyond the `sipy.sparse` API in a very quick manner.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`diags` from scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

A = np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
B = scipy.sparse.diags([A[:,0], A[:,1]], [0, 1], [4, 5])
```

When I `print B.todense()`, it gives me

```
[[ 1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  5.  6.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  7.  8.]]
```

Comment: More compactly: `sparse.diags(A.T,[0,1],(4,5)).A`